# Django channels or periodic ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-channels

Need some pro tips. I use django rest framework + vue js for my web application project and developed an easy chat app. The messages refresh dynamically by sending ajax requests every 2 seconds on the client part. Should I keep this variant or it's better to use django channels instead?

Comment: This might be better suited for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com - stack overflow is mostly for highly focused specific issues (usually with code) than more broad engineering choices. Good luck!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913676/dynamic-updates-in-real-time-to-a-django-template for more information on django-channels Vs AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***[image: long-polling]***, 
TL;DR on why long-polling?
a websocket is for a two way communication and HTTP request one way communication which last once the request is responded.
You can use django-channels to setup a long-polling; as specified in [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/routing.html?highlight=longpolling#urlrouter).
Why not just simply keep requesting the server using HTTP over and over again?
ans: For every request of http a preprocessing(maybe authentication) would take place which cost unnecessary computation power and time.