# How do I make highly scalable chat app with django?

Tags: django, ajax, websocket, redis, chat

I am currently using ajax , on set interval page would refresh giving a real time feel but i fear on long run if if it scale will clients have the problem, as page refresh every second I think it may overload server, which is the best option for a real time chat app using django, except redis(not free and it has limit)

The app should be scalable upto 1000 concurrent connections

Server is vps with 4 core 4gb ram and 4tb bandwidth

Comment: You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913676/dynamic-updates-in-real-time-to-a-django-template)

Comment: Explore web sockets